# how to edit custom xml from pull to refresh library?

Tags: android, xml, colors, attr, pull-to-refresh

I have to implement a library of `PullToRefresh` in my project.

I need to change the text color of the "loading..." and "pull to refresh". So I read the doc inside the project and I understood that it needs to be done in the xml, but I'm not sure how.

I have tried to add "color=0x0" and stuff like that but it didn't work .

This is the resource file to be changed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <declare-styleable name="PullToRefresh">

        <!-- A drawable to use as the background of the Refreshable View -->
        <attr name="ptrRefreshableViewBackground" format="reference|color" />

        <!-- A drawable to use as the background of the Header and Footer Loading Views -->
        <attr name="ptrHeaderBackground" format="reference|color" />

        <!-- Text Color of the Header and Footer Loading Views -->
        <attr name="ptrHeaderTextColor" format="reference|color" />

        <!-- Text Color of the Header and Footer Loading Views Sub Header -->
        <attr name="ptrHeaderSubTextColor" format="reference|color" />

        <!-- Mode of Pull-to-Refresh that should be used -->
        <attr name="ptrMode">
            <flag name="disabled" value="0x0" />
            <flag name="pullFromStart" value="0x1" />
            <flag name="pullFromEnd" value="0x2" />
            <flag name="both" value="0x3" />
            <flag name="manualOnly" value="0x4" />

            <!-- These last two are depreacted -->
            <flag name="pullDownFromTop" value="0x1" />
            <flag name="pullUpFromBottom" value="0x2" />
        </attr>

        <!-- Whether the Indicator overlay(s) should be used -->
        <attr name="ptrShowIndicator" format="reference|boolean" />

        <!-- Drawable to use as Loading Indicator. Changes both Header and Footer. -->
        <attr name="ptrDrawable" format="reference" />

        <!-- Drawable to use as Loading Indicator in the Header View. Overrides value set in ptrDrawable. -->
        <attr name="ptrDrawableStart" format="reference" />

        <!-- Drawable to use as Loading Indicator in the Footer View. Overrides value set in ptrDrawable. -->
        <attr name="ptrDrawableEnd" format="reference" />

        <!-- Whether Android's built-in Over Scroll should be utilised for Pull-to-Refresh. -->
        <attr name="ptrOverScroll" format="reference|boolean" />

        <!-- Base text color, typeface, size, and style for Header and Footer Loading Views -->
        <attr name="ptrHeaderTextAppearance" format="reference" />

        <!-- Base text color, typeface, size, and style for Header and Footer Loading Views Sub Header -->
        <attr name="ptrSubHeaderTextAppearance" format="reference" />

        <!-- Style of Animation should be used displayed when pulling. -->
        <attr name="ptrAnimationStyle">
            <flag name="rotate" value="0x0" />
            <flag name="flip" value="0x1" />
        </attr>

        <!-- Whether the user can scroll while the View is Refreshing -->
        <attr name="ptrScrollingWhileRefreshingEnabled" format="reference|boolean" />

        <!--
            Whether PullToRefreshListView has it's extras enabled. This allows the user to be 
            able to scroll while refreshing, and behaves better. It acheives this by adding
            Header and/or Footer Views to the ListView.
        -->
        <attr name="ptrListViewExtrasEnabled" format="reference|boolean" />

        <!--
            Whether the Drawable should be continually rotated as you pull. This only
            takes effect when using the 'Rotate' Animation Style.
        -->
        <attr name="ptrRotateDrawableWhilePulling" format="reference|boolean" />

        <!-- BELOW HERE ARE DEPRECEATED. DO NOT USE. -->
        <attr name="ptrAdapterViewBackground" format="reference|color" />
        <attr name="ptrDrawableTop" format="reference" />
        <attr name="ptrDrawableBottom" format="reference" />
    </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

I need the text to be in black color.

This is the link to the library (credit) :

https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All changes to the layout can be done in res->layout->***.xml

Here you can find the label/textview and change the color.

Answer (score 4):

You have to define `ptrHeaderTextColor` and/or `ptrHeaderSubTextColor` in your layout file when using `PullToRefresh` container as

```
<com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ptr="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/pull_refresh_scrollview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scrollbars="none"
ptr:ptrAnimationStyle="flip"
ptr:ptrMode="pullFromStart"
ptr:ptrHeaderTextColor="@android:color/white"
ptr:ptrHeaderSubTextColor="@android:color/white" >

...

</com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! For anyone who doesn't know: all the possible PTR attribs are shown in /res/values/attrs.xml

Answer (score 1):

you have pull_to_refresh_text textview id into your res library folder. Make it black...